# In-House iOS App Distribution - kind of APNS certificate?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, in-house-distribution

Which kind of APNS certificate should we use for In-House App Distribution?
Sandbox or production certificate?
And is there an official documentation for that?

Comment: It has to be a production one since you sign an app with the production certificate not a development one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Production, I've build many InHouse apps and production works. 
The sandbox only works with development builds.

I understand the confusing the Apple documentation states:

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is available only to apps
>   distributed through the iOS App Store or Mac App Store. Your app must
>   be provisioned and code signed to use app services. If you are a
>   company, most of these configuration steps can be performed only by a
>   team agent or admin.

But the production is the one you should use for any app supplied to users. Thus also the AdHoc version.